# Extracting value from MongoDB DBObject using Scala/Casbah

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

I want to extract a value of a certain key, "orderItems" in this case, from the DBObject returned from Casbah's MongoCollectionBase.find(...). I have the solution but I am not satisfy with it. I found my solution cumbersome. It casted and converted the java.util.Map returned from DBObject.toMap to Scala Map or other collections at every step.  What is the better way to to this? Thanks

```
val orders = provisioningDb("systems").find(MongoDBObject.empty, MongoDBObject("company.department.orders" -> 1))

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

def findC(m : Map[String, Any]) : Iterable[Any] = {
  val c = for ((k, v) <- m) yield (k, v) match {
    case (k, v) if k equals "orderItems" => v
    case (k, v : java.util.HashMap[String, Any]) => findC(toMap(v).asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]).head
    case _ => Nil
  }
  c.filter(_.isInstanceOf[java.util.List[Any]] )
}

def toMap[K, E](m: java.util.Map[K, E]): Map[K, E] = {
  Map.empty ++ new MapWrapper[K, E](m)
}

val orderItems = for {
  x <- orders
} yield x

for (y <- orderItems) {
  println(findC(toMap(y.toMap).asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]))
}
```

The 2 rows sample data with details removed which persisted in MongoDB,

```
company : {department : {orders -> [{"id" : "543", "quantity" : 2}, {"id" : "223", "quantity" : 21}, {"id" : "332", "quantity" : 3}] 


company : {department : {orders -> [{"id" : "222", "quantity" : 8}, {"id" : "663", "quantity" : 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into using a `case class` along with [Salat](https://github.com/novus/salat/wiki/Quick-start)?

You can also check this great [presentation](http://repo.novus.com/mongonyc-salat), specifically slide  [#28](http://repo.novus.com/mongonyc-salat/#28) which talks about SalatDAO which allows you to directly persist and retrieve your case objects!